# Removing node does not update in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to remove a node from the `GridPane` but when I do `gridPane.getChildren().remove(node)`, it doesn't seem to be updated in the UI. I have a label that comes up when there's an empty `TextField`, and when they are filled it should say **Order added**. But when the empty `TextField` label comes up and when I actually fill them up, **Please fill all fields** doesn't go away and **Order added** is just right on top of it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InputPane extends HBox
{
    ArrayList < Order > orderList;

    private HandlePane handlePane;

    TextField textField1 = new TextField();
    TextField textField2 = new TextField();
    TextField textField3 = new TextField();

    Label prodName, quantity, price, fill = new Label();

    Button place_an_order;

    GridPane gridPane;
    TextArea textArea;

    public InputPane(ArrayList < Order > list, HandlePane pane)
    {
        this.orderList = list;
        this.handlePane = pane;

        prodName = new Label("Prod. Name");
        quantity = new Label ("Quantity");
        price = new Label ("Price($)");
        prodName.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        place_an_order = new Button("Place an Order");

        gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(10,20,10,20));
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);

        gridPane.add(prodName, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(textField1, 1,1);
        gridPane.add(quantity, 0,2);
        gridPane.add(textField2, 1,2);
        gridPane.add(price, 0,3);
        gridPane.add(textField3, 1,3);
        gridPane.add(place_an_order, 1,4);

        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setText("No order");
        textArea.setPrefSize(320,120);

        this.getChildren().addAll(gridPane, textArea);

        ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
        place_an_order.setOnAction(handler);
    }

    private class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler < ActionEvent >{
        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
            String productStr = textField1.getText().trim();
            String quantityStr = textField2.getText().trim();
            String priceStr = textField3.getText().trim();

            fill.setTextFill(Color.web("FF0000"));
            fill.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

            if (productStr.isEmpty() || quantityStr.isEmpty() || priceStr.isEmpty())
            {
                fill.setText("Please fill all the fields");
                fill.setTextFill(Color.web("FF0000"));
                fill.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            }else{
                fill.setText("Order added");
                fill.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
                gridPane.add(fill, 0,0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**With empty fields:**

[image: This is what happens when at least one text field is empty]

**With filled fields:**

[image: And that's what happens when I actually fill the text fields]

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Probably you're calling the first block multiple times. This is all wrong anyway; just add the label once, without any condition, and then set its text in the `if` and `else` blocks accordingly.

Comment: What is the **direct parent** of your text fields? Is it gridPane or is there a sub-container with your fields on it?

Comment: Could you provide the FXML file, please?

Comment: @kleopatra hey I've just edited my code. Is that how you want it? I'm new to this so I'm not familiar with the way things work

Comment: @James_D when i do set the text in the `if` and `else` statement, it doesn't go update onto the pane immediately

Comment: read the referenced help page and do what it suggests :)

Comment: @0009laH the direct parent is gridPane. I don't have an FXML file because I'm not using Scene Builder

Comment: As requested, post a [mre]. But clearly what you state is not true, because a label with the text "order added" is visible.

Comment: It's really hard for me to understand why this question was upvoted. It's completely unanswerable as it's posted, and cannot possibly be useful to other users.

Comment: @James_D yea but I want "Please fill all fields" to go away

Comment: Have you tried deleting `gridPane.getChildren().remove(fill);` and `gridPane.add(fill, 0,0);`?

Comment: By the way I hate SceneBuilder but I use FXML files because it lightens Java code and the UI initialisation part becomes more readable.

Comment: @0009laH yep but it doesn't even print on the UI

Comment: @0009laH okay it prints both when needed but when printing "order added", "Please fill all fields" is not going away

Comment: You create a new `Label` every time the button is pressed, so obviously if the button is pressed twice you will have two labels in the UI. As I stated earlier, *just create a single label and add it once to the grid pane, and then change its text in the event hander*. And, for like the third time, post a [mre] if that instruction is not clear enough.

Comment: I've attempted at creating a reprex but I don't know whether I'm doing it right so please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you click on your button, the `handle` method:

1. Instantiates a new `Label` instance called `fill`
2. Checks whether all fields are completed.

When that condition is true, it executes `gridPane.getChildren().remove(fill);`, but `fill` has just been instantiated in step 1 and is not a children of `gridPane` yet, so the instruction **doesn't do anything**.

When the instruction `gridPane.add(fill, 0,0);` is executed, you add the `fill` label (with text "Order added") inside the grid pane and you get this **overlay effect** when executing `handle` several times.

This is not a JavaFX bug; each cell of a `GridPane` behaves line a `StackPane`, so you can perfectly **add labels above each other**.

---

I would recommend you to:

- Remove the `gridPane.getChildren().remove(fill);` instruction
- Move `gridPane.add(fill, 0, 0);` outside the `handle` method; you have to execute this line **once** (at the initialization of the component).

  ```
  private class ButtonHandler implements EventHandler <ActionEvent> {
      Label fill;

      public ButtonHandler() {
          fill = new Label();
          fill.setTextFill(Color.web("FF0000"));
          fill.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

          gridPane.add(fill, 0, 0);
      }

      public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
          String productStr = textField1.getText().trim();
          String quantityStr = textField2.getText().trim();
          String priceStr = textField3.getText().trim();

          if (productStr.isEmpty() || quantityStr.isEmpty() || priceStr.isEmpty()) {
              fill.setText("Please fill all the fields");
              fill.setTextFill(Color.web("FF0000"));
          } else {
              fill.setText("Order added");
              fill.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to move ```gridPane.add(fill, 0,0);``` outside the ```handle``` method. I've also instantiated the label at the start of the code so it doesn't create new ones over and over.

Comment: @JarrellTan I've updated my answer :) Is it good for you?